# Slicing a tensor with a tensor of indices and tf.gather

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to slice a tensor with a indices tensor. For this purpose I am trying to use `tf.gather`.
However, I am having a hard time understanding the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) and don't get it to work as I would expect it to:

I have two tensors. An `activations` tensor with a shape of `[1,240,4]` and an `ids` tensor with the shape `[1,1,120]`. I want to slice the second dimension of the `activations` tensor with the indices provided in the third dimension of the `ids` tensor:

```
downsampled_activations = tf.gather(activations, ids, axis=1)
```

I have given it the `axis=1` option since that is the axis in the `activations` tensor I want to slice.

However, this does not render the expected result and only gives me the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,0,1] = 1 is not in [0, 1)
```

I have tried various combinations of the `axis` and `batch_dims` options, but to no avail so far and the documentation doesn't really help me on my path. Anybody care to explain the parameters in more detail or on the example above would be very helpful!

**Edit:**
The IDs are precomputed before runtime and come in through an input pipeline as such:

```
features = tf.io.parse_single_example(
            serialized_example,
            features={ 'featureIDs': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)}
```

They are then reshaped into the previous format:

```
feature_ids_raw = tf.decode_raw(features['featureIDs'], tf.int32)
feature_ids_shape = tf.stack([batch_size, (num_neighbours * 4)])
feature_ids = tf.reshape(feature_ids_raw, feature_ids_shape)
feature_ids = tf.expand_dims(feature_ids, 0)
```

Afterwards they have the previously mentioned shape (`batch_size = 1` and `num_neighbours = 30` -> `[1,1,120]`) and I want to use them to slice the `activations` tensor.

**Edit2:** I would like the output to be `[1,120,4]`. (So I would like to gather the entries along the second dimension of the `activations` tensor in accordance with the IDs stored in my `ids` tensor.)

Comment: How did you generate the tensor ids?

Comment: @qmeeus: I have edited the original post to answer your question.

Comment: @budekatude Just so that I am not getting myself confused, what is the output dimension you're expecting in this case?

Comment: @Daveldito: I have added another edit above to answer your question.

Comment: are you sure that the error is thrown when you use axis=1? The error says that the index you provide (=1)is out of the size of the axis (axis = 1  size is 240  !!!) .Ithink the error will be thrown if the axis=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `tf.gather` Gather slices from `params` axis `axis` according to indices.

Granted that the documentation is not the most expressive, and the emphasis should be placed on the **slices** (since you index slices from the `axis` and not elements, which is what I suppose you mistakenly took it for).

**Let's take a much smaller example:**

```py
activations_small = tf.convert_to_tensor([[[1, 2, 3, 4], [11, 22, 33, 44]]])
print(activations_small.shape) # [1, 2, 4]
```

Let's picture this tensor:

```
    XX 4  XX 44 XX XX
  XX  3 XX  33 X  XX
XXX 2 XX   22XX  XX
X-----X-----+X  XX
|  1  |  11 | XX
+-----+-----+X
```

`tf.gather(activations1, [0, 0], axis=1)` will return

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]]], dtype=int32)>
```

What `tf.gather` did was to *look from* axis 1, and picks up index 0 (ofc, two times i.e. `[0, 0]`). If you were to run `tf.gather(activations1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], axis=1).shape`, you'd get `TensorShape([1, 5, 4])`.

**Your Error**
Now let's try to trigger the error that you're getting.

`tf.gather(activations1, [0, 2], axis=1)`

> InvalidArgumentError: indices[1] = 2 is not in [0, 2) [Op:GatherV2]

What happened here was that when `tf.gather` looks from axis 1 perspective, there's no item (column if you will) with index = 2.

I guess this is what the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather#args) is hinting at by

> `param:<indices>` The index Tensor. Must be one of the following types: int32, int64. Must be in range [0, params.shape[axis]).

**Your (potential) solution**

From the dimensions of `indices`, and that of the expected result from your question, I am not sure if the above was very obvious to you.

`tf.gather(activations, indices=[0, 1, 2, 3], axis=2)` or anything with indices within the range of indices in `[0, activations.shape[2])` i.e. `[0, 4)` would work. Anything else would give you the error that you're getting.

There's a verbatim answer below in case that's your expected result.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comprehensive answer and the example!

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
downsampled_activations =tf.gather(activations , tf.squeeze(ids) ,axis = 1)
downsampled_activations.shape #  [1,120,4]
```

In most cases, the tf.gather method needs 1d indices, and that is right in your case, instead of indices with 3d (1,1,120), a 1d is sufficient (120,). The method tf.gather will look at the axis( = 1)  and return the element at each index provided by the indices tensor.

Comment: You may pass `axis=[0, 1]` to `tf.squeeze` to ensure that the two first dimensions and only those are squeezed, which can be useful to catch errors if `ids` does not have the expected shape `(1, 1, 120)`.